# Convert Markdown to HTML algorithm interview question - best approach?

Tags: algorithm, text-processing, text-parsing, converters

I recently got this question in a technical interview and ran out of time.

The task was to write a Markdown to HTML converter. Given the following input:

```
This is a paragraph with a soft
line break.

This is another paragraph that has
> Some text that
> is in a
> block quote.

This is another paragraph with a ~~strikethrough~~ word.
```

Produce the following output:

```
<p>This is a paragraph with a soft<br />line break.</p>

<p>This is another paragraph that has <br />
  <blockquote>Some text that<br />is in a<br />block quote.</blockquote>
</p>

<p>This is another paragraph with a <del>strikethrough</del> word.</p>
```

The formatting of the output is not important, just has to be valid HTML.

I can't think of a good approach to do this. The only thing I can think of is to split by double newlines to get paragraphs, and then iterate over each paragraph to check for the presence of each special symbol and replace is with its HTML equivalent. It feels hacky though and I believe that there is a more structured way to approach this class of problems, bearing in mind this is an interview setting with a time limit of roughly 30 minutes.

I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt in one hour c#.

The code repeatedly strives to merge adjacent lines if possible.
It takes additional time to tune this for readability and performance.
Some extra error checking would be fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace akMdConverter
{
    class Program
    {
        const string Break = "<br />";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var md = new string[]
            {
                "This is a paragraph with a soft",
                "line break.",
                "",
                "This is another paragraph that has",
                "> Some text that",
                "> is in a",
                "> block quote.",
                "",
                "This is another paragraph with a ~~strikethrough~~ word."
            };

            md = MergeBlockQuotes(md);
            md = MergeSoftLineBreaks(md);
            md = MergeParagraphs(md);
            ReplaceStrikeThroughs(md);

            foreach (var m in md)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
        }

        static string[] MergeBlockQuotes(string[] md)
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();
            string previousLine = "";

            foreach(string line in md)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(">"))
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        previousLine = previousLine + Break + 
                                       line.Substring(1).Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousLine = line.Trim();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        lines.Add(previousLine);
                        previousLine = "";
                    }
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            return lines.ToArray();
        }

        static string[] MergeSoftLineBreaks(string[] md)
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();
            string previousLine = "";

            foreach (string line in md)
            {
                if ((line == "") || line.StartsWith(">"))
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        lines.Add(previousLine);
                        lines.Add(line);
                        previousLine = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        previousLine += Break;
                    }

                    previousLine += line;
                }
            }

            if (previousLine != "")
            {
                lines.Add(previousLine);
            }

            return lines.ToArray();
        }

        static string[] MergeParagraphs(string[] md)
        {
            var lines = new List<string>();
            string previousLine = "";

            foreach (string line in md)
            {
                if (line == "")
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        lines.Add(Bracket(previousLine, "p"));
                        previousLine = "";
                    }
                    lines.Add("");
                }
                else if (line.StartsWith(">"))
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        previousLine += Break + "\n";
                    }

                    previousLine += Bracket(line.Substring(1), "blockquote");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (previousLine != "")
                    {
                        previousLine += Break;
                    }

                    previousLine += line;
                }
            }

            if (previousLine != "")
            {
                lines.Add(Bracket(previousLine, "p"));
            }

            return lines.ToArray();
        }

        static string Bracket(string s, string bracket)
        {
            return "<" + bracket + ">" + s.Trim() + "<" + bracket + "/>";
        }

        static void ReplaceStrikeThroughs(string[] md)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < md.Length; i++)
            {
                string s = md[i];

                int tilde1 = s.IndexOf("~~");
                while (tilde1 >= 0)
                {
                    int tilde2 = s.IndexOf("~~", tilde1 + 2);

                    if (tilde2 > tilde1)
                    {
                        s = s.Substring(0, tilde1) + "<del>" + 
                            s.Substring(tilde1+2, tilde2 - tilde1 - 2) + "</del>" + 
                            s.Substring(tilde2 + 2);
                        tilde1 = s.IndexOf("~~");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tilde1 = -1;
                    }
                }

                md[i] = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Axel for taking your time to show a way to do it. Do you think you could have written it in 30 minutes, in an interview setting? 

I found one Python library that converts Markdown to HTML and looked at the source code - it used regular expressions throughout.

Comment: No, I could not program it in half an hour. It might be possible to sketch a grammar for this markdown subset and write a small recursive descent parser. If your are allowed to use tools like Bison and Flex to generate parser and scanner, half an hour would be possible.